# Сборка проекта с гитхаба в Jenkins

Tags: cmake, jenkins

Как собрать `c++` проект с гитхаба в Jenkins при помощи плагина CMake?

UPD. Решил попробовать запустить проект с локального репозитория без CMake
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но возникает ошибка  `cd:can't cd to /home/mt/Test`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего, Вам нужно добавить хуки Дженкинса в гитхабе. А также, установить плагин гитхаба в сам дженкинс

Comment: укажите, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), 1. какой именно тип проекта вас интересует: freestyle или pipeline. 2. с какими именно трудностями столкнулись при конфигурации проекта.

Comment: Разве можно только с помощью freestyle или pipeline? Просто CMake и Github плагина не достаточно?  Я лично пытался только при помощи этих двух

Comment: Трудности с которыми я столкнулся - не знаю как настроить плагин CMake в Jenkins, чтобы сделать сборку проекта с гитхаб репозитория, без pipeline. Информации по этому почти нет.

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1121135/178576)

Comment: freestyle и pipeline — это два кардинально разных **типа** проектов. другие типы — уже производные от этих двух. plugin-ы github и cmake используются для конфигурации проекта. и в том и в другом реализована поддержка и того и другого типа проектов.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, не требуется установка ни того ни другого plugin-а. они лишь добавляют некоторые удобства: plugin git отлично и сам справляется с забором исходников, а программу cmake отлично можно запустить и без дополнительного plugin. если она, конечно, установлена на сборочной node.

Comment: 1. ну вот откуда на сборочной node возьмётся каталог из вашей локальной файловой системы? вы же хотели что-то с гитхаба скачать? скачали? вот и собирайте. 2. и в следующий раз, когда вам очень захочется написать слово «sudo», подумайте, а нужно ли его здесь писать. потом ещё раз подумайте о том же самом. и в третий раз подумайте. и если все три раза придёте к выводу: «да, надо!» только тогда его и пишите. p.s. делать что-нибудь наугад, не читая хотя бы вводных руководств — обычно не самый лучший способ разобраться.